# kmz file from dropbox or google drive

Tags: google-maps, kmz

I want to provide KMZ file link from **dropbox**/**google drive** on my google map so Google map can parse it as KMZ file needs to be parsed from public hosted domain but I am unable to find a way:

```
<script>
var map;
var src = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-_cUzmUSQEoYUNlSzN5cVNmd0k/view';//link of google drive but its saying invalid document

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer((src), {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport: false,
        map: map
    });
    console.log(kmlLayer)
    kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
        var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
        var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
        testimonial.innerHTML = content;
    });
}
```

Comment: if the dropbox / google drive are not directly accessible (without  password or access control) you  can't  the kmlLayer (as all the google maps feature) work only for  fully accessible link

Comment: how can i create a fully accessible link

Answer (score 0):

if  (as is) the dropbox / google drive are not directly accessible (without  password or access control) you  can't  the kmlLayer (as all the google maps feature) work only for  fully accessible link

for this don't use dropbox or google drive but a  host you kmz on a hosting  service  .. there a  lot of free  hosting service on internet  ..where you can store you files with ftp features and accessing by a normal  url (without password controll access)