# How to display my KML File in my google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps

Hi good afternoon someone do you know why can not displayed my kml is storage  in Dropbox?
I know that kml cant be storage in localhost and is needing in place  public to acces and putted kml in my map
The question is why dont show my kml in my map? Im new trying with this. I made sure that the folder is public where I have my kml

```
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      var src = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3t3u4y3ytxgkj1/Distrito_4.kml?dl=0';

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.5962502, -100.3962371),
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
          suppressInfoWindows: true,
          preserveViewport: false,
          map: map
        });
        kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
          var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
          var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
          testimonial.innerHTML = content;
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKeyhidden&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [kmz file from dropbox or google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854603/kmz-file-from-dropbox-or-google-drive)

Answer (score 0):

To use a direct link to a KML file on dropbox, use `dl=1` (rather than `dl=0`)

```
var src = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3t3u4y3ytxgkj1/Distrito_4.kml?dl=1';
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {map: map});
```

reference:  [Re: Don't kill Public folders (on the Dropbox forum)](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-files-folders/Ending-support-of-public-folder/m-p/198007/highlight/true#M67791)

> you can turn shared links into direct links by changing "dl=0" to "dl=1"
> in the URL.  It would be nice if there were an account setting to make that default.

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**working code snippet:**
(with your KML)

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var map;
    var src = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3t3u4y3ytxgkj1/Distrito_4.kml?dl=1';

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.5962502, -100.3962371),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
      });

      var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        preserveViewport: false,
        map: map
      });
      kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
        var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
        var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
        testimonial.innerHTML = content;
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```